# SVG tricky keyTimes behaviour

Tags: animation, svg

I am making an animated SVG donut chart. My best try for the moment is [here](http://madhead.tk/doughnut_5_example.svg). But this is not exactly what i want. I want the elements appear at the start, then fade out before another one has appeared on the screen, then wait for all other elements to appear and fade out, and then to start this cycle again from the first element. As you see, now elements are fading in/out together, only their animation start times differ. I tried values/keyTimes attributes in [another try](http://madhead.tk/doughnut_5.svg). But the animation is not working in any browser i know.

Here is the problem code in first SVG:

```
<animate
    attributeName="opacity"
    begin="0ms" //This is for the first element, for anothers it differs
    //I wish there is `pause` attribute, to pause animation repiting...
    dur="3000ms"
    from="0.7"
    to="0"
    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

Here is another code sample

```
<animate
    attributeName="opacity"
    begin="0ms"
    keyTimes="0,0.2,1"
    values="0.7,0,0"
    dur="15000ms"
    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

As you see, i tried to increase animation duration, but to end fading of element at 20% (i have five elements to fade) of this time. But it does not work.

Tried reordering attributes, using `from` and `to` with two-valued `keyTimes` and long `dur` with no effect. There must be some cunning trick here...

P.S. [This](http://madhead.tk/doughnut_5_no_repeat.svg) is almost what i want, but i need animation to repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is commas in `keyTimes` and `value` attributes - need to use semicolons and read docs twice.